# Disc space doesn't add up to what "Storage" states in Windows 10

Tags: storage, windirstat

I am trying to clear some storage on my computer but I am unable to find out where or how to clear it. On the generic Windows 10 Storage page, it states that I have used 913GB out of 914GB for "This PC". I ran two tests using WinDirStat and another tool. They both stated that for my entire computer I have used 123.5GB and for my"C drive 76.2 GB out of 76.4 GB. Help I am really confused on why Windows 10 states that I have 914 GB and my C drive is only 76.4 GB.

[image]
[Wiz Tree screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLsUN.png)
[image]
<sup>**WinDirStat**</sup>

[Disk Management screen shot showing partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ53e.png)

Comment: You have something weird going on, WInDirStat, is saying files were last changed in 2023.  I would trust Storage Sense over WInDirStat.  Use [WizTree](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wiztree-finds-the-files-and-folders-using-the-most-disk-space-on-your-hard-drive/) instead as an Administrator.

Comment: IMHO `WinDirStat` doesn't work on your version of Windows, or quite possibly isn't as effective a tool as it may claim. Look elsewhere for your second opinion if you feel you can't trust the information Windows is providing.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using Wiztree and same results (There is a hyperlink in between the two pictures

Comment: So WizTree is reporting the correct information.  So what exactly is your question?  You can use Disk Cleanup to remove your previous installation of Windows

Comment: My hard drive is has 1TB of storage. It is a toshiba dt01aca100, why does it only show less than 100 GB?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Downloaded EaseUS Partition Software and lowered the partition size to a couple of GB higher than what the capacity was saying on the Windows program. After the reboot, I had over 800GB of unused storage. I then just expanded my C drive up to 900GB using the unused storage and it worked instantly! Now my C drive shows over 900GB of storage instead of the 74GB capacity.